# How to show page number on title page in Jasper report 4.0.1

Tags: jasper-reports, title, page-numbering

I have a report with a subreport printed in the Title. My report uses the option to print the page numbers in the footer. But whatever I try, on my first page (the Title) the page numbers are not displayed.
I have tried to place the pagenumber in the subreport, but that always shows page 1 of 1 on the first page of a 3 pages report.
Does anyone have an idea how I can show the page number on the Title page?

Answer (score 0):

If by '*Title*' you mean the ***Title Band***, than this is normal because this band is printed only once for the whole report. But there is another band that does what you are requiring, `Page Header` which gets printed on top of each page of the output file. Try to place the page number expression in it instead.